# Reverse a string while keeping it in a single line

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to reverse a string using the code:

```
puts("Hi now it's going to be done!")
string = gets.chomp.to_s
i = string.length
while i >= 0
  puts(string[i])
  i = i - 1
end
```

It prints the string in backward order, but each word is on a single line. How can I keep all of them on a single line?

Comment: "Huh?" Please show *actual* input and current / *expected* output - the words after "It's working" are ambiguous. Also, a little bit of question formatting makes it a much more palatable read.

Comment: use `print` instead of `puts`

Comment: Why not just use `String#reverse`?

Comment: You don't need the `to_s`.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` adds a newline to the end of the output if one isn't already present.

`print` does not. So do this:

```
while i >=0
  print string[i]
  i=i-1
end
puts
```

The final `puts` is because you want any further printing to be on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"Hi now it's going to be done!".chars.inject([]) { |s, c| s.unshift(c) }.join
```

Or This is a little easier to follow:

```
string = 'Hi now it's going to be done!'
string.reverse!
```